# Search facet user entered date field display

Tags: 7, search

I've recently started working on an existing Drupal site that uses Apache Solr search & have come across a problem when configuring facets.

The search index just indexes one type of content & one of the facets it displays from this is a year field, this is set as a date select field where the user can select a month & year. If I set this to only allow one entry it works fine and the facet links have the years that are available with the number of results it'll return in brackets.

When I set the field to allow an unlimited number of values instead of getting a list of years as links I get what seems to be a random number "1414800000 (1)," timestamp maybe? It also seems to group them by the month & year entered rather than just the year as it did when only one field entry was allowed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If anyone else has this same problem, there is a [patch on drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/node/2104623). If you've not used to patches, See this [beginner's guide](https://www.drupal.org/node/620014).